# How do I access a variable thats inside of a Firebase method?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

So I have two references in my code. One gets total money earned this month and the other one gets total money spent this month.

I get incomings with this block of code

```
val incomeSumReference = database.getReference("users").child(uid).child("Incomes").child(
    currentYear.toString()
).child(currentMonthInString.toString())
incomeSumReference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        var sum = 0.0

        for (dataSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
            var map = dataSnapshot.getValue() as Map<*, *>
            val sumOfIncomes = map.get("itemValue")
            var sumo = sumOfIncomes.toString()
            var sumAsDouble: Double? = sumo.toDouble()
            sum += sumAsDouble!!
            var stringSum = sum.toString()
            var incomeSumToFormated = formatNumberString(stringSum) // this is what I want to get

            profitTextView.text = "+$" + incomeSumToFormated.toString()

        }
    }

    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
    }
})
```

And this is my spent money reference code block

```
val spentSumReference =  database.getReference("users").child(uid).child("Expenses").child(
    currentYear.toString()
).child(currentMonthInString.toString())
spentSumReference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        var sum = 0.0
        for (dataSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
            var map = dataSnapshot.getValue() as Map<String, Object>
            val sumOfIncomes = map.get("itemValue")
            var sumo = sumOfIncomes.toString()
            var sumAsDouble: Double? = sumo.toDouble()
            sum += sumAsDouble!!

            var stringSum = sum.toString()
            var spentSumToFormated = formatNumberString(stringSum) // this is what I want to get outside 

            spentTextView.text = "-$" + spentSumToFormated.toString()
        }
    }

    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
    }

})
```

I have a textview called totalBalance and I want to do something like this

```
var income = incomeSumToFormated.toDouble

var spent = spentSumToFormated.toDouble

var total = income-spent

totalBalance.text = total.toString
```

I tried to declare incomeSumFormated and spentSumFormated outside of the method but it doesn't work.

**Edit**

Here I demonstrate my intentions using screenshots of my application.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Edog4.jpg

I thought the easiest way would be just to get incomeSumFormated and spentSumFormated results and set the text of balance to their difference. Like I wrote up there:

```
var income = incomeSumToFormated.toDouble

var spent = spentSumToFormated.toDouble

var total = income-spent

totalBalance.text = total.toString
```

I will also post screenshots of my firebase database to show you how it looks.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Yh5T.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/d00ND.jpg

Comment: "it doesn't work" Why not? What line in the code that you shared doesn't do what you expect from it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen So as you can see my incomeSumToFormated variable is inside of a for loop which is also inside of onDataChanged method. If I want to access it I should declare it outside of the loop. But when I do that, I check its value with Log.d but it returns textview widget not the sum of income money.

Comment: Have you tried to use nested listeners? Does it work that way?

Comment: @AlexMamo not really. Guess I am not that familiar with it.

Comment: I have edited my question so you understand it more clearly